# Are there any possibilities to recover data from dead hard disc

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I have an `Sea-gate 500gb` hard disc that is completely dead, i mean when i connect hard disc to my system it is not getting detected.

But i had so much of important data in it, i need those data now.
Are there any way to get them back or get it repaired?

Are there any possibilities to recover the data from that dead hard disc from any special hardware???

How can i solve this???

Comment: Punch "data recovery" into your favorite search engine. There are many such services available.

Comment: Can you see the harddisk in the BIOS?

Comment: @Marcel No, i am not able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the hard drive is physically dead or if the partition might be corrupt. If the partition is corrupt it is possible, but otherwize it's much harder. If you plug in the hard drive to the computer, open powershell and enter "diskpart" and then "list disk". Can you see the hard drive?